# Scrapy to crawl forum, Xpath does not work

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I want to use scrapy to get the post data of the following forum page:
https://www.motor-talk.de/faq/mercedes-e-klasse-w210-q89.html

The code I tried is found below. The first part works, and returns the required text. However the second part returns absolutely nothing, and the spider just ends.

Does anyone have an idea if the XPath, that I got from Chrome is wrong, or is something else wrong?

I have also attached the output that i get from my Macs Terminal.

[Picture of Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvjbc.png)

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.motor-talk.de/faq/mercedes-e-klasse-w210-q89.html#Q3512477',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for text in response.xpath('//*[@id="questions"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/p[15]/i/text()'):
            yield {
                'text': text.extract(),
            }
        for text in response.xpath('//*[@id="questions"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/p[1]/text()'):
            yield {
                'text2': text.extract()        
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
response.xpath("//div[@class='statictext']//div[@class='bbcode']/text()")
```